# How to make a button appear as if it is pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, button

Using VS2008, C#, .Net 2 and Winforms how can I make a regular Button look "pressed"?
Imagine this button is an on/off switch. 
`ToolStripButton` has the Checked property, but the regular Button does not.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

One method you can used to obtain this option is by placing a "CheckBox" object and changing its "Appearance" from "Normal" to "Button" this will give you the same functionality that I believe you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably also use the ControlPaint class for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need a `ToggleButton`. You can take a look at third party vendors of WinForms components such as Telerik, DevExpress, ComponentFactory, ViBlend which provide such control. They all provide toggle buttons.

Comment: Excellent.  Purchase a third-party library for a fundamental button.  How many billions of dollars and thousands of developers would it take before Microsoft provides core functionality out of the box?