# how to make my button looks like it is being clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a textbox and some buttons on a form in my windows application. 
The user can enter his data either from buttons or from the textbox.
I want the buttons to look like they are being clicked when the user enters the data from the text box.

I mean while the user is typing in the textbox the related buttons look like they are being clicked.

I am using .Net and c#

Thank you.

Comment: 4 years - crikey. I'll bet you can push water uphill with a rake too.

Comment: do you mean disabled perhaps? whats the purpose of "look like it is being clicked"?

Comment: This site is less than 3 years old..

Comment: This site hasn't been up for 4 years ...

Comment: You'd have thought after using this site for 4 years you'd not how to phrase a good question :)

Comment: If you had been using the site for long, you would know better than to include "hi" in your question, or to tell us it's your first post.

Comment: @John: I say hi in all my questions! Are we not supposed to?

Comment: I used to use 'hi' in all my quIestions. I thought I was being polite. But then I noticed people editing it out everytime. So I stopped. I guess it's bad form, but, am not sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a button appear as if it is pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913/how-to-make-a-button-appear-as-if-it-is-pressed)

Comment: @Phil @341008 Just "Hi" is ok, but a long preamble cuts into the summary text which is displayed in the question list.

Comment: @Phil: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: please be patient a little with me , I am trying to learn how to use this site correctly , after all these comments I thought that I did a very big mistake!!!!......it is just a question

Comment: Ahmad: I think your question was good, just not very well written, and maybe a duplicate. If [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913/how-to-make-a-button-appear-as-if-it-is-pressed) doesn't help you, try asking again and try to be really clear about what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I understand your question correctly:

You will need to create an event that triggers when someone types in the textbox(s), and then use `btnName.Enabled = false` in the event function.