# Is there a way to visibly simulate a mouseclick with just a button itself?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've seen here: [How to make a button appear as if it is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913/how-to-make-a-button-appear-as-if-it-is-pressed) how to make a button in a winforms application look pressed (and that it stays pressed) in 2008.

In my application I travel a similar route there but what I'm trying to do is to get more a feel like a mouse has clicked the button. Thus it becomes pressed for a second and then unpressed again (just like with a regular mouse click).

What I'm wondering there is if in 2017+ that Checkbox Workaround is still the best Approach even for this route (and it Needs to be "checked" and "unchecked") or if there is a better approach there (thus also one possible with the button itself)?

Comment: You answering your own question. [Simulate mouse click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416748/how-to-simulate-mouse-click-in-c)

Comment: @reniuz wow oO that means I either have to use the Checkbox Approach or create a "mouse Simulator"? I sincerly had hoped that there was a more easy (and handily) approach than something like that oO.  If that is the only way then I dare say my question could be seen as a duplicate there to that question (as the answer will be the same there).  Like mentioned I hope there is a different possible way, but if then ouch (then the Checkbox is the most easy Approach as hurtful as it is).

Comment: You can use the checkbox approach and set checked == true, or false in your code.

Comment: @MichaelTralala yepp and I would Need to put a delay in between the two. Still I had hoped that tehre is a better Approach possible there (but as mentioned that will then the way be if I have to decide between the implementation of the mouse Simulator and the Checkbox (if no other way exists for Buttons themselves).

Comment: What is the "easy and handily way"? 6 lines of code and extension method is super easy and handy for me.