# Visual Studio Windows.Forms Button Background Color selected when Click

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, button

//Hi,
I want to write a Software and am confused about "keeping the buttom selected (i mean the background color) when button is clicked, until i click on another one"

If someone could help me, i would appreciate that so much.
Thanks in advance//

```
namespace SoftwareUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
        }

        private void button1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.ForeColor = Color.GhostWhite;
        }

        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.ForeColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is enough information here to diagnose the problem. If you want a button background colour to be set on click (as in your Click handler) and keep that colour until something else happens then remove the other mouse event handlers.

Comment: Are these what you want:  [How to make a button appear as if it is pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4913/3744182) and [ToggleButton in C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/282118/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

Add this code for click event of all buttons:

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
b.BackColor = Color.LightGray;

foreach (Button bt in b.Parent.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    if (bt != b)
        bt.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```